# The use of the verb "tell" in context

Tags: grammar

Is the verb used naturally in the following sentence.

> I left the money on the table, but I forgot to **tell** my wife.

Do I need to use *about it* after the *wife*

Comment: I think the sentence is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase including "**tell**" is preceding the phrase including the "**leaving of money**".
As they  both are connected, it is well understood that the "telling" is about the "leaving", hence "about it" is **NOT** necessary.

Comment: Actually, the clause with *tell* follows the other one, both in terms of the sentence itself and in terms of the sequence of events described. It doesn't precede it. (If the sentence read *but I forgot to tell my wife ahead of time that I would do so*, then you could interpret the described event—of not doing so—as temporally preceding the act of leaving the money on the table.) However, the one preceding the other or not, the *referent* of the *tell* clause is still understood to be the *left* clause, so it doesn't need further clarification. Adding *about it* is fine, but it's not required.